# PHP 'MongoClient' Not Found

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

There are tons of questions on this topic, but none of them have worked for me. I originally had the mongodb driver installed (and working) using

```
sudo pecl install mongo
```

however according to the pecl output this has been deprecated and replaced with

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

So I installed that, changed `mongo.ini` to load `extension=mongodb.so` instead of `mongo.so` (as instructed to by the output of the above `pecl` command) . When I load my phpinfo() page it shows that it is loaded

```
mongodb version 1.0.0
mongodb stability stable
libmongoc version 1.2.0
libbson version 1.2.0
```

However, when I try to use MongoClient in my PHP page, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /srv/www/site/functions.php on line 500
```

I have exhausted all of the 'similar questions' suggested when creating this question, as well as google searches. So I'm hoping someone has some first-hand experience with fixing this because I feel like I'm out of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the class names have changed in the new driver. So `MongoClient` not existing is a valid error.

`new MongoDB\Driver\Manager` is the replacement for `MongoClient`